# Problem is I only received email with the same Name services

Tags: powershell

I created a PowerShell script that will email alerts when services is not running which is set to auot-start.
Problem is I only received email with the same Name services. See image below.
Below is the script.

```
#$Credd = Get-Credential
#$Credd | Export-Clixml -Path C:\Script\EmailCred2.txt
$Credd = Import-Clixml -Path C:\Script\EmailCred2.txt

#Call/Get the hostname
$ServerName = $($env:computername)

#Email Parameters
$From = "alerts@mydomain.com"
$To = "myemail@gmail.com"
$Subject = "Alert: Failed to Start $($service.Name) on $ServerName $(Get-Date)"
$Body = $Subject
$SMTP = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"

#Get all the services which the property start type is equal to Automatic
$GetServices = (Get-Service | Where-Object { $_.StartType -eq 'Automatic' })

#Where the value in $ServerName object collection will pass it to the $computer variable  
foreach ($computer in $ServerName) {

#Collecting the result in $GetServices statement
foreach ($service in $GetServices) {

    #use condition if service status is not equal to running
    if ($service.Status -ne 'Running') {

      #error handling using try and jump to catch blocks if somethings goes wrong                                                     
      try {
            #starting the services based on the condition and terminating the error to able to catch it
            Start-Service $service -ErrorAction Stop
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
            Write-Host "$($service.Name) is now running on $($ServerName)"
                      }
    
    Catch {
            #Print out the error message
            Write-Host "$($Error[0])" -ForegroundColor Red 

            #send email alerts
            Send-MailMessage -From $From -To $To -Subject $Subject -SmtpServer $SMTP -Body $Body -Credential $Credd -UseSsl -Port $SMTPPort
           }
         }
      }
 }
```

[image]

I'm expecting the result should email me the services Name one at a time.
not the same services.

Comment: You only ever define the `$subject` _once_, before actually inspecting any of the services. Move the `$Subject = ...` and `$Body = ...` lines down into the loop, just before calling `Send-MailMessage`

Comment: That's make sense. It works as expected. Thank you Mathias, it helps a lot